# How to change Page Title format in MS OneNote 2013

Tags: fonts, styles, microsoft-onenote-2013

I was used to having my Page Titles in Calibri, but in some update there came a new style for Page Titles that is Calibri Light, and I can't figure out how I change that style from Light to Normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to File->Options->General
2. Choose a new font for your default font and press OK
3. (this step may not be necessary) Create a new page, type a title and verify that the new font is used
4. Go back to options, select Calibri for default font, and click OK
5. Your new pages should now use Calibri as the default font even for titles.

Comment: Thanks for trying. The default font has been Calibri all along, I did go in, changed the default font size. Saved it, opened a new page. Calibri appears on the normal text, but the title still appears in Calibri Light. Very annoying. Just to make sure, I also changed the default font to Book Antigua, again normal text appeared in Book Antigua, but the title remained Calibri Light.

Comment: @user293129 huh, that's interesting. I attempted this by changing my font to times new roman then back to calibri, and the titles of new pages used whatever the default font was. Just to be clear I understand your problem, was it existing notes you checked for the new font or only new notes? I assume the latter because you said the body works. I have ON2013, like you have tagged this, but perhaps there could be something slightly different about the versions. I'll get a bit more detail about which version this worked for me in, and see if i can try and reproduce your issue. Cheers, -Brad

Comment: It was a sudden change, I assume there must have been some update at the time, but since I don't use the application daily I didn'r notice immediately. It is the Desktop 201 version. Could it have something to do with syncing over OneDrive? That on one of my devices I only have Calibiri Light (to be honest I don't think that would hold true since Calibri is my default font in all Office programs on all my devices(